# Get Value Of PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, validation, reflection

I'm creating a small validation framework, I've a custom `Validation Attribute` which is assignable to methods and a `IsValid` property in `ValidationCore` class. When `IsValid` called inside the method my `ValidationCore` finds a caller method and get its attribute assigned to method. My custom `Validation` attribute has a property name named `TypeToValidate`. So when I find validation attribute I look for any types in class scope of that type. I don't have any problem till now, but the problem is when I want to get the value of property which I've to validate I don't have any instance of that class to get that property value. I don't know how can I handle this situation please help me.

This is my sample :

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static TestModel Model { get; set; }
    public static ModelValidator ModelState
    {
        get { return new ModelValidator(); }
    }

    [Validate(typeof(TestModel))]
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something else....
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit :** This is my `IsValid` property

```
    public virtual Boolean IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            // Get IsValid caller method
            var method = GetCallerMethod();

            // Get method attribute
            var Attrib = GetMethodAttribute(typeof(ValidateAttribute), method);

            // Get model to validate inside class scope
            var modelProperty = GetModelToValidateInClassScope(Attrib, method);

            if (modelProperty != null)
            {
                ValidateModel(modelProperty);
            }

            ....
        }
    }
```

and here is `ValidateModel` method :

```
    protected virtual void ValidateModel(PropertyInfo modelProperty)
    {
        // Here I've model property
        // But I can't get its value
        var model = modelProperty.GetValue(null, null);
        var properties = model.GetType().GetProperties(
                        BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
                        BindingFlags.Public |
                        BindingFlags.Instance |
                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);


        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            // Add error to error list
            GetPropertyErrors(model, propertyInfo);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance for which to get the property value of.  It looks like you need to modify the method `GetModelToValidateInClassScope` so that it returns the instance of the model itself, along with the PropertyInfo.

If this method is changed so it looks something like this (note the new **out** parameter):

```
PropertyInfo GetModelToValidateInClassScope(Type attributeType, MethodInfo methodInfo, out object instance)
{
   // same implementation as before ...

   // assign the model to use, 
   // which is likely accessible from somewhere in the is method
   instance = theModelInstanceFromThisMethod;

   // .. or if the property is static, then uncomment the next line:
   // instance = null;

   // same return value as before ...
}
```

I'm just guessing here because you didn't provide the implementation of this method.  If `GetModelToValidateInClassScope` doesn't have access to the model instance, then you'll have to get it from somewhere else.

Once you get the model instance, it could be used like the following.  Note that `ValidateModel` has been modified so that it accepts the model instance as the first parameter.

```
...   

    // Get model to validate inside class scope 
    object instance;  // <--- will hold the model instance
    var modelProperty = GetModelToValidateInClassScope(Attrib, method, out instance); 

    if (modelProperty != null) 
    { 
        ValidateModel(instance, modelProperty); // <--- make sure to pass the instance along!
    } 

...

protected virtual void ValidateModel(object instance, PropertyInfo modelProperty)         
{         
    // get value of instance property
    var model = modelProperty.GetValue(instance, null);    

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the question actually asked**

> I don't have any problem till now, but the problem is when I want to get the value of property which I've to validate I don't have any instance of that class to get that property value.

If it's a static property, that's fine - just use `null` as the first argument:

```
// First argument is the instance: null as it's a static property
// Second argument is indexer arguments: null as we don't have any
var value = property.GetValue(null, null);
```

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx):

> Because static properties belong to the type, not individual objects, get static properties by passing null as the object argument.

**Alternative approach**

If you're just trying to get the `TypeToValidate` property from the `Validate` attribute, then you *should* have an instance of the attribute, and you can just cast to `ValidateAttribute` and retrieve the property directly.

Basically, it's not clear where properties really come into what you're trying to do. Your attribute is on a *method* rather than a property, and your attribute doesn't say which properties to validate...

Comment: Its not working, I tried that before. Also property could be none-static.

Comment: @SaberAmani: It *does* work, so you must be doing something else wrong. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. If the property *isn't* static then obviously you need an instance to fetch the value from.

Comment: @SaberAmani: See my edit - your question is really unclear at the moment, as it's not clear where you're getting a `PropertyInfo` from, or which property it is...

Comment: @SaberAmani: Your edit doesn't really clarify much, partly because it's calling various other methods you haven't provided. As I said before, a short but *complete* program (which doesn't have to demonstrate any validation - it just has to demonstrate the bit you're having problems with) would make things a lot clearer. As an aside, I'm not sure I'd use a property for `IsValid`, as it looks like it's doing quite a lot of work...